# Javascript setTimeout, multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm having trouble getting a setTimeout to work. I have three js files and I've tried to show the relevant code from them. The setTimeout is in evencard.js. If I remove js-decider.js and load flipcards2.js immediately on page load, the setTimeout works perfectly. However when I set it up as shown below, the setTimeout does not delay anything; The code inside the setTimeout function is ran immediately. Modernizr doesn't seem to be the issue because if I put a setTimeout inside js-decider.js it works.

**js-decider.js**

```
$(function() {

    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
        if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:680px)")) { 
        }
        else {
            $.getScript("js/flipcards2.js");
        }
    });

});
```

**flipcards2.js**

```
$(function() {

    $(".more-images").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active-more");
    });
    $('#page .container:odd .more-images').click(function() {
        evenCard();
    });

});
```

**evencard.js**

```
function evenCard() {

    var $thisElse = $('.active-more');

    function timeoutTriggerElse() {
        $thisElse.closest(".container").removeClass("hide");
    }

    setTimeout(function(){timeoutTriggerElse()},400);

    $('.active-more').removeClass("active-more");

}
```

Comment: js-decider.js and evencard.js are loaded on page load btw.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the error console?

Comment: Sadly there's no errors.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the setTimeout() does not delay anything"?  What problem are you seeing?  You do know you're only requesting a 400ms delay, right?

Comment: Well it's a little hard to explain. I just need to delay the replacing of an image for a split second to avoid a flickering effect. I'm doing a kind of flip cards effect using CSS3 transformations...

Okay, I did discover that it does have something to do with the modernizr if statement or the window bind. When I remove all of that and just run  `$.getScript("js/flipcards2.js");` in js-decider.js it works. I don't know if I'm supposed to link off to anything on there besides jfiddle but this is what I'm working on:

(http://www.benteegarden.com/SAMPLE/ben.html)

Comment: Perhaps you should be using the transitionEnd event on the CSS3 transitions to trigger your event rather than a `setTimeout()`.  Anyway, it sounds like you're on the trial of the actual problem with the Modernizr `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using Enquire instead of Modernizr and it works great. Modernizr was the issue after all.

(http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#lowdown)